# $.each() adds "undefined" value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

The below code works just fine except for the annoying *undefined* I am getting when appending elements dynamically retrieved from a *JSON multidimensional array*. I could not figure out from where it is coming, however, I assume it is coming from declaring a variable outside function and using it inside `$.each()` to accumulate data.

```js
var c = 0;
var q = 1;
$.each(json, function (i, data) {
  var answers; // declared here and outside this function - same results.
  $.each(data.answers, function (i, a) {
    answers += '<tags>' + a + '</tags>'; // the problem is here "maybe".
  });
  $('.foo').append(answers); // I get "undefined" ahead of values retrieved.
});
```

> **[Playground](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/HuTg3/)**

Comment: `var answers` should go outside of both `$.each` calls, under `var q`.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan The formatting was off. I've fixed the indent.

Comment: Advise you to use a javascript template engine, like [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) or [JsRender](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender), or other you choice. Your code will be much cleaner

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I'm declaring var answers inside first loop, because I need to reset it, in order not to add up new values from previous second loop. If I declare it outside, all values in second loop will be appended. And yea, you're right about *the man who sold the world* =)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You get 'undefined' ahead of your results because you use `+=` and start with an undefined `answers` variable.

Try declaring `var answers = '';`.