# Jquery mobile choice from json

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am getting JSON data and show in HTML, in `fieldset` with radio choices but when I show the HTML code it puts "undefined". Here is my code, thank you:

```
var str_html;
var str_html;
str_title = item.title || null;
str_title = item.title || null;
str_subtitle = item.quest || null;
str_image = item.image || null;
a_paragraph = item.paragraph || null;
str_html = '<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true">';
str_html += '<legend>' + item.subtitle + '</legend>';
str_html += '<input name="radio-choice-h-' + item.id + '" id="radio-choice-h-' + item.id + '" value="on" checked="checked" type="radio" >';
str_html += '<label for="radio-choice-h-' + item.name + '>Si</label>'
str_html += '<input name="radio-choice-h-' + item.id + 'b" id="radio-choice-h-' + item.id + '" value="on" checked="checked" type="radio" >';
str_html += '<label for="radio-choice-h-' + item.subname + '>No</label>'
str_html += '</fieldset>';
$page.find("#test_container").append(str_html);
```

Comment: var `str_html = '';`. use only one, why two?

Comment: possible duplicate of [$.each() adds "undefined" value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19036278/each-adds-undefined-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one of the properties of your JSON object is probably missing. 
You also need to fix a missing double quote:

change

```
str_html += '<label for="radio-choice-h-' + item.subname + '>No</label>'
```

into

```
str_html += '<label for="radio-choice-h-' + item.subname + '">No</label>'
```

My guess is that the combination of an 'undefined' property together with the unclosed attribute is causing this 'undefined' to show in your html