# Code returns 'undefined"

Tags: javascript

Why is this piece of code returning `undefined` ?

http://jsfiddle.net/hdy3grgj/

```
function getMoods(nb) {
        var index;
        var moods;
        var a = ["MOOD0001", "MOOD0002", "MOOD0003", "MOOD0004", "MOOD0005", "MOOD0006", "MOOD0007", "MOOD0008", "MOOD0009", "MOOD0010", "MOOD0011", "MOOD0012", "MOOD0013", "MOOD0014", "MOOD0015", "MOOD0016"];
        for (index=0; index<=nb; ++index) {
                if(index==0 || index==4 || index==8 || index==12) { moods += '<div class="col-xs-4">'; }
                        moods += 
                                '<div class="checkbox">'
                                    +'<label for="'+a[index]+'">'
                                        +'<input type="checkbox" id="'+a[index]+'" class="moods"> '+a[index]
                                    +'</label>'
                                +'</div>';
                if(index==3 || index==7 || index==11) { moods += '</div> '; }
        }
        $("#moods-area").html(moods);
}
getMoods(12)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [$.each() adds "undefined" value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19036278/each-adds-undefined-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the initial value of `moods` is `undefined`, as it was never itialized (declared, yes; initialised, no); changing:

```
var moods;
```

to:

```
var moods = '';
```

There is no 'undefined': [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/hdy3grgj/1/).

Answer (score 1):

You get the "undefined" in the beginning of your string because you are not setting a value for `moods`, and the adding a string to it. It will then convert `moods` to a string, which turns out "undefined", and add some content to it. To fix this, use `var moods="";` instead of `var moods;`

Answer (score 1):

The initial value of `moods` is `undefined`. See what happens when I add a string to an uninitialized variable:

```
> var foo;
> foo + 'bar';
"undefinedbar"
```

**Solution**: Initialize the variable with an empty string.